# Dynamically choose ad networks for ad serving

Tags: android, ads

My Android app uses two ad network SDKs: A1 and A2.
I would like to send the traffic to the ad network which generates the highest revenue at the current time. (Or send, say, 30% of traffic to A1 and 70% to A2).

Can this be done programmatically?

Comment: I don't know if is it possible, but if is it, I suggest to before load the ad, take the hour, compare with a range and decide if you have to show A1, or A2.